Isuues with pyinstaller (Module Not found)
I have created a Python (.PY) file thatuses the Tkinter package inside it and executes perfectly in Spyder.
Now I am trying to convert it to .EXE file using pyinstaller package, once I convert tried to run and got the below error:

The version of packages are as below:

Python 3.11.7

import tkinter
tkinter.TkVersion



8.6 -




 import tkinter

tcl = tkinter.Tcl()
print(tcl.call("info", "patchlevel"))


8.6.12 -


This question is similar to: ImportError: No module named 'tkinter' after pyInstaller. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks Jerry i have tried with that link and error still exists

Are you sure both spyder and pyinstaller are using same Python environment?

Yes both are in same environment

I cannot reproduce the issue if both spyder and pyinstaller are using same Python environment.  The testing script using tkinter can be executed after converting to executable.

Provide more info, are you using '--onlfile' or specfile ?
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py

Using "pyinstaller --onefile Script_name.py

try with your pyinstaller full path, like C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts
C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller --onefile Script_name.py

Thyanks ,  tried the error exits the same

I can help you because I have already completed this conversion. Please share more information.
share simple code instead of the entire code and also share what cmd you tried on the cmd prompt.


uninstalled pathlib package
Copied pyinstaller.exe file to folder where script(python311/scripts) is located
opened cmd - CD 
C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts\pyinstaller --onefile registartion_script.py


can you share a sample code, I can run it on my system and will share fix code.

Did you run pyinstaller with --paths?
pyinstaller --paths projectName/lib/python3.11/site-packages script.py
I recommend you to use venv for every projects

Thanks , i have edited my code as above and still problem exists

Try upgrading tkinter
pip install tkinter==<version> --upgrade

@LokeshSenthilkumar Note that tkinter cannot be installed or upgraded via pip command.

Run pyinstaller command in anaconda prompt instead windows cmd then able to get answer
